# Webservice consumer optimalization

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile-6.5, .net-cf-3.5

I am writing a .NET application for Windows Mobile 6.5 (based on 3.5 CF).

I imported the wsdl and Visual Studio (2008) generated a webservice consumer, I can see the code in Reference.cs and I have a vague understanding of what it does.

The application is consuming a webservice. And I need it to be faster (customer demands). Right now a roundtrip takes about 500ms, I found the backend takes about 200ms which means my part is the bottleneck with 300ms.

Before I start trying and writing code to try things out, maybe someone else can provide the answers to these question, avoiding me a lot of trouble and work.

The webservice itself is hardly customizable, there are a few options that do not seem to have a lot of effect (URL behaviour, preauthenticate).

Upon googling I found 2 statements:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704594.aspx says I could create a pre-generated XMLSerializer. Only this article is about MS Dynamics CRM. Does it apply to Visual Studio? I have the feeling the Reference.cs is already XMLSerializer-code.
- http://blog.westmonroepartners.com/mobile-web-services-jsonrest-vs-xmlsoap/ here I found the quote

> the .NET Compact Framework on Windows Mobile, JSON deserialization was
>   literally thousands of times faster than XML deserialization due to
>   poor performance of .NET reflection on the platform.

So that could be something. I could go for JSON, or, since the amount of operations/properties is very limited (and I do not expect a lot of changes) I could write some code to deserialize without using Reflection. 
The questions: can somebody validate the quote? Would not using Reflection be an answer to my optimization-question?

Thanks in advance for all your great insights and shared knowledge :-)

Comment: You may go with JSON. But remeber the limitted resources available in a mobile device and the network latency, these will always be a bottleneck. Transposing high sohisticated code, ideas and modelling from desktop to mobile is never a good idea in regards of performance. Normally a mobile device should only have to use network data on startup or in background and cache all needed data locally.

Comment: I am writing an application in which the "state" it should be in (which form should be in display, which input data is expected, etc) is decided on a server. The server will give me its data in each way I want, I just need to know what the most efficient way is :-)